# Oracle Single row subquery returns multiple rows while using nested subquery

Tags: oracle, ora-01427

I'm trying to run a query as below but it throws 'Single row subquery returns multiple rows'  error. It works with = in place of <> though(returns more than 50 rows as final output). Not able to figure out whats going wrong when I use <>.Tried NOT IN, doesn't work. Please help.

```
select a,
       b,
       c,
       d,
       e 
from 
   (select distinct column1 as a,
                    column2 as b,
                    column3 as c,
                    column4 as d,
                    column5 as e
     from t1
     where t1.column1 like 'DOMAIN.%')
where c||d||e <> 'YYY'
```

Comment: I don't see any single row subquery here.

Comment: Is t1 a complex view, perhaps?

Comment: @mustaccio True that, me neither :|

Comment: @AlexPoole No its a table, a,b,c,d,e are retrieved based on complex functions on the columns though.Guess that shouldn't matter. Could it be a data issue?

Comment: @Shabuja is this select statement being used inside another query?

Comment: Is the exception coming from the query itself or from one of the functions - can you add the error stack, especially if it indicates a PL/SQL error? There are some bugs related to this error (see MOS note 18832.1 for a list); nothing obviously relevant but you've hidden a lot of detail.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hunch but I think you are missing the inline view alias in your query here as shown below

```
from 
   (select distinct column1 as a,
                    column2 as b,
                    column3 as c,
                    column4 as d,
                    column5 as e
     from t1
     where t1.column1 like 'DOMAIN.%') XXX <-- this one
```

Also, try using `CONCAT()` function instead like

```
where concat(concat(c,d),e) <> 'YYY'
```

Comment: `concat()` doesn't work how you think it works - it only accepts two parameters [as per the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm). You'd have to nest `concat()` calls in order to concatenate 3 or more items together. IMHO, it's far more readable to use the `||` method of concatinating items.

Comment: @Boneist, yes that's true. edited answer. Actually it's a hunch but concat operator should work as well. It's worth givng a try though.

Comment: I'm not questioning whether concat (when used correctly) would work; it's a question of how readable it is. I find `c||d||e` far easier to read and understand at a glance than `concat(concat(c,d),e)`! Someone else used concat in a question recently and I had to apply suitable indenting etc to work out what they were doing! YMMV, of course, but I'm all for making code easy to read and maintain! *{:-)

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your inputs. I have found the cause of the error- it was due to the subquery used to fetch column3 which I assumed as harmless. It fetched more than 1 row and couldnt fit into 'c'.